# Passing {ClassName} vs passing {<ClassName>} as react component porps. What is the difference?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react development. I often came accross code examples where a component takes other component as props, like so:

```js
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import { UserInfo } from './userinfo';

const UserPanel = (props) => {
    return (
        <UserInfo icon={<AccountCircleIcon/>} user={props.user}>
            {props.children}
        </UserInfo>
    );
}
```

Other time, I see component that takes class name as one of its props. Like so:

```js
import { Admin } from 'react-admin';
import { AppLayout } from './components';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Admin layout={AppLayout}>
      {* other codes here ... *}
    </Admin>
  );
}
```

What's the difference? If both approach can be used to achieve the same effect, which one is considered better?

Comment: Are you looking for the difference for elements sent as props vs props.children? If so, check this: [https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891),

Comment: @VladMoisuc My question is highlighted in the title. Perhaps I need to highlight the code examples. The first code example shows a ```<UserInfoComponent/>``` component that takes ```<AccountCircleIcon/>``` compoennt as its props. The second code example showing a ```<Admin/> component that takes ```AppLayout``` class as its props. My question is, whats the difference between the two appoach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that on the **first code**, you're calling the render function on your component and passing the result render as a prop. On **the second code**, you're sending the component (**not rendered yet!**) as a prop and will use it to render in another place of your tree.

**Essentially they're the same and it's up to how you want to drive passing props on your project.**

Just to illustrate, consider that you have two components:

```js
// Returns a JSX.Element
function AccountCircleIcon() {
  return (<>Foo</>)
}

// Also, returns a JSX.Element
function AppLayout() {
  return (<>Bar</>)
}

function App() {
  return (
     <>
      // The two lines below will produce exactly a JSX.Element
      <AccountCircleIcon/>
      {AppLayout()}

      // Dependency prop here will be a valid React component
      // Like a function you can call: AppLayout()
      <AnotherComponent dependency={AppLayout}/>


      // Dependency prop will be also valid React component
      // but it's already rendered.
      <AnotherComponent dependency={<AccountCircleIcon/>}/>
     </>
  )
}
```

[Check this out to understand and play a little bit with the idea.](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-matsumoto-dyr6v)

Comment: So when is one is more appropriate to be used than the other?

Comment: @bluearth it's a matter of style, to be completely honest. When calling `<AccountCircleIcon/>`, basically you're calling React.createElement() and producing a simple object, not doing any mounting or lifecycle event. There is no performance difference. At the end of the day is more like how you want your code to look. I could see scenarios where you want to be prop-drilling just the `AppLayout` instead of the result of a render, but like I said, at the end of the day there is zero difference.